# recover EditText from a RecyclerView item (from the adabter to myActivity)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

hi guys I need help I'm using android studio java for the first time ...
this is my interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9QKk.jpg)

I wanna recover the EditText value in a list when the user clicks in "valider la commande"

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve that value, you should have an array declared in your recycler views adapter, in which you write each value whenever the user changes it.

You should also add a public method to retrieve that array from your adapter class. So on, in your button onClickListener you just retrieve that array from your adapter using the public method.

Here is an example:

```
class AsistenteAdapter(var names: ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AsistenteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //DECLARE HERE YOUR ARRAY VARIABLE (SAME SIZE AS names.size)

    class ViewHolder(var binding: ComponentApuntadoContainerBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ComponentApuntadoContainerBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )

        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //ADD HERE YOUR LOGIC TO SAVE THE VALUE
        //Put on text changed listener to your EDITTEXT, so that whenever the text is changed, the value is saved in your array
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return names.size
    }

    public fun getValues(): //ARRAY {
      return //YOUR ARRAY VARIABLE
    }
}
```